# merging two ordered lists of numbers into one with recursion

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, merge, pattern-matching

I am new to Haskell, recursion 
for e.g. INPUT [1,3,4,5] [6,9,8,10]
OUTPUT = [1,3,4,5,6,8,9,10]
My previous attempt was

```
>let addlist [] [] = []

>let addlist (a:as) (b:bs) = (a+b) : addlist as bs
>let x = [1..5]
>let y = [6..10]
>addlist x y
```

But this adds the numbers in the list rather than merging them.

Comment: 9 comes before 8 in the input, but not in the output. Is this intentional? If so, by what logic is the order of the output chosen?

Answer (score 2):

what about

```
let { addlist (a:as) (b:bs) = if  a<= b then  a : addlist as (b:bs) else  b : addlist (a:as) bs; 
addlist [] bs = bs; 
addlist as [] = as }
```

which is equivalent to

```
addlist (a:as) (b:bs) = if  a <= b then  a : addlist as (b:bs) else  b : addlist (a:as) bs
addlist [] bs = bs
addlist as [] = as
```